# is there a way to do batch download for all gene pathways?

Tags: bioinformatics

I would like to download all the gene pathways and genes of each pathway. Preferably, gene length of each gene as well. It would be a lot more convenient if there is an R package.

Comment: in what format do you want the pathways? You can bulk download the SBML files. Also, please clarify what you mean by "*download the genes of each pathway*".

Comment: What pathways? From which database? What species?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using KEGG [REST](http://www.kegg.jp/kegg/docs/keggapi.html).

http://rest.kegg.jp/link/pathway/hsa ## list of all genes and pathways in Humans

Comment: Do you mind showing me how you got this file?

Comment: You can find it in the rest page.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with BioCyc pathways you can use their [REST-API](http://biocyc.org/web-services.shtml) for batch-downloading all genes for their pathways. You can run a wide range of queries including BioVelo-queries for all genes/compounds in a specified pathway, all pathways in organism etc. A query for all the pathways in B. subtilis would look like:

[http://biocyc.org/xmlquery?[x:x%3C-bsub](http://biocyc.org/xmlquery?%5bx%3ax%3C-bsub)^^pathways]

Where you get an XML with the Cyc-IDs for the pathways which can be used to search for the genes. A query for all genes in the Arginine synthesis pathway in B. subtilis would then look like:

[http://biocyc.org/xmlquery?[x:y:=bsub~argsyn-pwy,x%3C-%28genes-of-pathway%20y%29]&detail=full](http://biocyc.org/xmlquery?%5bx%3ay%3a=bsub~argsyn-pwy,x%3C-%28genes-of-pathway%20y%29%5d&detail=full)

Which returns an XML with information regarding the genes, start and end positions including (i.e. gene length). Since I don't work very much in R I don't know if there exists an R-package. But it is very straightforward to write Python scripts for downloading and XML-parsing.